# Xamarin Google Authentication

Tags: azure, xamarin, google-authentication

I am attempting to implement backend server authentication for my App Service in Azure using Google.  I used the [this](https://causerexception.com/2017/12/03/google-native-login-with-xamarin-forms/) guide to implement authentication in my app.  It works until I  add in .RequestIdToken(serverClientId or .RequestServerAuthCode.

```
 public GoogleManager()
    {
        Instance = this;
        String serverClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestEmail()                            
            .RequestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
            .Build();

        _googleApiClient = new 
     GoogleApiClient.Builder(((MainActivity)Forms.Context).ApplicationContext)
            .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))                
            .Build();
    }
```

I have verify that my ClientID and ClientSecret are the same in both Azure, GoogleAPIs, and the Xamarin App.  The will return GoogleApi will return a status code of 10 when it fails but I can't find any message that associates to that.  I believe it has something to do with the ClientId I provided.

Comment: For `requestIdToken`, you could follow [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), for `requestServerAuthCode`, you could follow [Enabling Server-Side Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access). Moreover, you could use fiddler to capture the network traces to narrow down this issue.

Comment: Since you mentioned App Service in Azure, I assume that you could leverage [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and follow [How to configure your Azure app to use Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication), and [Add authentication to your Xamarin Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users).